# E: Unable to locate package ros-dashing-desktop while installing ROS 2 via Debian Packages

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I am new to ROS, I am trying to install ROS2 for gym_gazebo2 but getting this error message even after following the exact procedure.
I am following instructions from: https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Installation/Dashing/Linux-Install-Debians/
The codes are as follows:

```
root@ubuntu:/home/priyam# sudo apt update && sudo apt install curl gnupg2 lsb-release
Hit:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                   
Hit:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease           
Hit:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease
Hit:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
272 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
lsb-release is already the newest version (11.1.0ubuntu2).
lsb-release set to manually installed.
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  curl gnupg2
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libcurl4
1 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 271 not upgraded.
Need to get 401 kB of archives.
After this operation, 462 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libcurl4 amd64 7.68.0-1ubuntu2.4 [234 kB]
Get:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 curl amd64 7.68.0-1ubuntu2.4 [161 kB]
Get:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 gnupg2 all 2.2.19-3ubuntu2 [5,316 B]
Fetched 401 kB in 4s (111 kB/s)    
(Reading database ... 185904 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libcurl4_7.68.0-1ubuntu2.4_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libcurl4:amd64 (7.68.0-1ubuntu2.4) over (7.68.0-1ubuntu2.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package curl.
Preparing to unpack .../curl_7.68.0-1ubuntu2.4_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking curl (7.68.0-1ubuntu2.4) ...
Selecting previously unselected package gnupg2.
Preparing to unpack .../gnupg2_2.2.19-3ubuntu2_all.deb ...
Unpacking gnupg2 (2.2.19-3ubuntu2) ...
Setting up gnupg2 (2.2.19-3ubuntu2) ...
Setting up libcurl4:amd64 (7.68.0-1ubuntu2.4) ...
Setting up curl (7.68.0-1ubuntu2.4) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.1-1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.31-0ubuntu9) ...

root@ubuntu:/home/priyam# curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/ros.asc | sudo apt-key add -
OK

root@ubuntu:/home/priyam# sudo sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=$(dpkg --print-architecture)] http://packages.ros.org/ros2/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs) main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros2-latest.list'
root@ubuntu:/home/priyam# sudo apt update
Hit:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                      
Hit:2 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu focal InRelease                       
Hit:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease    
Hit:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease   
Hit:5 http://packages.ros.org/ros2/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:6 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
271 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.

root@ubuntu:/home/priyam# sudo apt install ros-dashing-desktop
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ros-dashing-desktop
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/367717/e:-unable-to-locate-package-ros-dashing-desktop-while-installing-ros-2-via-debian-packages/) by [duttonide](https://answers.ros.org/users/65597/duttonide/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2020-12-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> ```
> Hit:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
> ```

you appear to be running Ubuntu Focal (ie: `20.04`).

ROS 2 Dashing is not supported on Focal.

See also [Installing ROS 2 Foxy Fitzroy](https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Installation/Foxy/) (which *is* supported on Focal) and [Installing ROS 2 Dashing Diademata](https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Installation/Dashing) which states the supported OS version: Ubuntu Bionic (or `18.04`).

And the page you link ([Installing ROS 2 via Debian Packages](https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Installation/Dashing/Linux-Install-Debians/)) has this right after the TOC:

> Debian packages for ROS 2 Dashing Diademata are available **for Ubuntu Bionic**.

Finally: [REP 2000: ROS 2 Releases and Target Platforms](https://www.ros.org/reps/rep-2000.html#dashing-diademata-may-2019-may-2021) also lists supported OS for Dashing.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-12-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [duttonide](https://answers.ros.org/users/65597/duttonide/) on 2020-12-15**:
Thanks it worked fine but this problem seems to appear as follows:

```
bash: /usr/share/gazebo-9/setup.sh: No such file or directory
root@ubuntu:/home/duttonide# source ~/ros2learn/environments/gym-gazebo2/provision/mara_setup.sh
bash: /usr/share/gazebo-9/setup.sh: No such file or directory
root@ubuntu:/home/duttonide# cd ~/gym-gazebo2/examples/MARA
bash: cd: /root/gym-gazebo2/examples/MARA: No such file or directory
root@ubuntu:/home/duttonide# python3 gg_random.py -g
python3: can't open file 'gg_random.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
root@ubuntu:/home/duttonide#
```

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-12-15**:
I'm not sure what those errors mean.

I would suggest you mark this question as answered (by clicking on the checkmark to the left of the answer), and then post a new question for your new problems.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-12-15**:
Also: I would advise you to *not* log into your system as `root`.

That's very much discouraged.